# Setting properties to a class in a loop overwrites the last properties

Tags: python

I am trying to set new properties to a class at runtime and attaching a lambda which behaviour depends on some property specific data. If I set the properties in a loop, as in class B, the first property gets overwritten. While setting them sequentially works. Can't find the problem. There is mention in other question that I should use `__getattr__` instead of properties, as in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967551/how-do-i-dynamically-create-properties-in-python). But I would like to understand what the issue here.

```
import time
class A():
    def __init__(self, dynprops = ['a', 'b']):

        setattr(A, 'a', property(lambda x: self.print_prop('a')))
        setattr(A, 'b', property(lambda x: self.print_prop('b')))

    def print_prop(self, dynprop):
        print(time.time(), dynprop)

class B():
    def __init__(self, dynprops = ['a', 'b']):

        for prop in dynprops:
            setattr(B, prop, property(lambda x: self.print_prop(prop)))

    def print_prop(self, dynprop):
        print(time.time(), dynprop)

a = A()
print(a.a)
print(a.b)
b = B()
print(b.a)
print(b.b)
```

gives

```
>> 1481137121.6755576 a
>> None
>> 1481137121.6756482 b
>> None
>> 1481137121.6757774 b
>> None
>> 1481137121.6758344 b
>> None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `prop` is changed to 'b' and then stays like that. The `lambda` function returns the current value of `prop`, not the value that was assigned to it during the creation of the `lambda`. To avoid this behaviour you should use a closure:

```
class B():
    def __init__(self, dynprops = ['a', 'b']):
        for prop in dynprops:
            setattr(B, prop, property(self.printer(prop)))

    def print_prop(self, dynprop):
        print(time.time(), dynprop)

    def printer(self, prop):
        return lambda x: self.print_prop(prop)
```